React - MUI | No encuentra los iconos
estaba probando la libreria MUI para react, y me he copiado un componente lista para ver como queda, asi tengo el app:
import { List, ListItem,ListItemAvatar,Avatar,ListItemText } from "@mui/material";
import {ImageIcon, WorkIcon,BeachAccessIcon} from '@mui/icons-material'


function App() {
  return (
   <div>
    <List sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemAvatar>
          <Avatar>
            <ImageIcon />
          </Avatar>
        </ListItemAvatar>
        <ListItemText primary="Photos" secondary="Jan 9, 2014" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemAvatar>
          <Avatar>
            <WorkIcon />
          </Avatar>
        </ListItemAvatar>
        <ListItemText primary="Work" secondary="Jan 7, 2014" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemAvatar>
          <Avatar>
            <BeachAccessIcon />
          </Avatar>
        </ListItemAvatar>
        <ListItemText primary="Vacation" secondary="July 20, 2014" />
      </ListItem>
    </List>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Pero estoy teniendo problemas con los iconos , los he importado como indico en el codigo pero ni aun asi los detecta, los errores que me dan son :
ERROR
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
createFiberFromTypeAndProps@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:330562:21
createFiberFromElement@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:330583:46
reconcileSingleElement@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:319682:49
reconcileChildFibers@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:319732:39
reconcileChildren@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:322671:32
updateHostComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:323315:24
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:324760:18
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:309752:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:309796:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:309853:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:329717:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:328965:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:328888:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:328861:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:328256:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:337776:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:337754:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:337991:25

